# Play 2 - Set header on all responses?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm aware from [Setting HTTP headers in Play 2.0 (scala)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199490/setting-http-headers-in-play-2-0-scala) that you can set response headers on a case-by-case basis by doing, for example, `Ok("hello").withHeaders(PRAGMA -> "no-cache")`.

What if you want to set that header, or a few different headers, on responses from all your Actions?  You wouldn't want to repeat the `withHeaders` everywhere.  And since this is more like an application-wide configuration, you might not want Action writers to have to use a different syntax to get your headers (e.g. `OkWithHeaders(...)`)

What I have now is a base Controller class that looks like

```
class ContextController extends Controller {
 ...
 def Ok(h: Html) = Results.Ok(h).withHeaders(PRAGMA -> "no-cache")
}
```

but that doesn't feel quite right.  It feels like there should be more of an AOP-style way of defining the default headers and having them added to each response.

Comment: Note that PRAGMA -> no-cache probably won’t work the way you intend. See this link: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/ You probably want to use CACHE_CONTROL instead of PRAGMA

Comment: `CACHE_CONTROL -> "max-age=0"` should do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `Global.scala`, wrap every call in an action:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.http.HeaderNames._

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  def NoCache[A](action: Action[A]): Action[A] = Action(action.parser) { request =>
    action(request) match {
      case s: SimpleResult[_] => s.withHeaders(PRAGMA -> "no-cache")
      case result => result
    }
  }

  override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
    if (Play.isDev) {
      super.onRouteRequest(request).map {
        case action: Action[_] => NoCache(action)
        case other => other
      }
    } else {
      super.onRouteRequest(request)
    }
  }

}
```

In this case, I only call the action in dev mode, which makes most sense for a no-cache instruction.

Comment: Lovely, thank you! I’d stumbled upon a similar solution, but was having problems matching the parameterised type SimpleResult without compiler warnings about erasure. Also, note my comment above about PRAGMA being the wrong thing to use for caching.

Comment: @MariusSoutier - i tried the solution you suggested, but at runtime, i always get _"other"_ and not an `Action` i can use to add headers to. the type of _"other"_ at runtime is: `play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$4` any idea on how i can deal with it?

Comment: regarding my previous comment: @BobG answer deals with that.

Comment: The type of the handler returned by `super.onRouteRequest(request)` changed in playframework 2.2. An updated version of this code working for 2.2 can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533289/overriding-onrouterequest-with-custom-handler-in-play-scala

Answer (score 14):

The topic is quite old now, but with Play 2.1 it is even simpler now.
Your `Global.scala` class should look like this :

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.http.HeaderNames._

/**
 * Global application settings.
 */
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  /**
   * Global action composition.
   */
  override def doFilter(action: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = EssentialAction { request =>
    action.apply(request).map(_.withHeaders(
      PRAGMA -> "no-cache"
    ))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve fine-grained control is in using wrapped actions. In your case it can be something like that:

```
object HeaderWriter {
    def apply(f: Request[AnyContent] => SimpleResult):Action[AnyContent] = {
        Action { request =>
            f(request).withHeaders(PRAGMA -> "no-cache")
        }
    }
}
```

and use it in such manner:

```
def doAction = HeaderWriter { request =>
    ... do any stuff your want ...
    Ok("Thats it!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too ways. You can use [action-composition](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaActionsComposition). Then you must declare at every Controller that you want set here the header. Another option is to use the [GlobalSettings](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaGlobal).
There are similar solutions for java, too.

Comment: I don't see where you can do this in GlobalSettings, can you be more specific?  It looks to me like you only have hooks into the request, not the response.

Comment: Well you can wrap the normal Action with your own. Then I think you have access to the result-object and there you can do it. Just an idea, because I'm working with java. There you have the context which contains the reponse.