# Discarding already set headers on Play Framework 2.x

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I want to "alter" headers which are set on `controllers.Assets.at`.

- I want to add a custom tag (I am able to do this by `withHeaders` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479424/play-2-set-header-on-all-responses?lq=1))
- **I want to delete a tag which is set previously**. Such as `Etag`

Since `.withHeaders` appends or overwrites an existing header, I am not able to delete with it. For Cookies there is `discardingCookies` but I am not able to see a similar one for headers.

And since `header: ResponseHeader` is a `val` in `PlainResult` I can't change its value directly.

**How can I delete an already set tag in Play Framework 2.x Scala?**

Code sample for what I am trying to do:

```
def at(file: String): Action[AnyContent] = CacheForever(Assets.at(assetDistDirectory, file))

def CacheForever[A](action: Action[A]): Action[A] = Action(action.parser) { request =>
  action(request) match {
    case s: SimpleResult[_] => {
      s.withHeaders(
        "mycustomheader" -> "is_set_here"
      )
      s.withOutHeaders("Etag","AnotherTagSetByAssetsAtButIDontWant")   
      // <--- I need something like the above line.
    }
    case result => result
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [implementation](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L286) of `withHeaders` with a little correction:

```
val without = Seq("Etag","AnotherTagSetByAssetsAtButIDontWant")
implicit val writeable: Writeable[A] = s.writeable
s.copy(header = s.header.copy(headers = s.header.headers -- without) )
```

With an implicit class:

```
implicit class SimpleResultHelper[A](val r: SimpleResult[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def withOutHeaders(without: String*): SimpleResult[A] = {
    import r.writeable
    r.copy(header = r.header.copy(headers = r.header.headers -- without ))
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val newS = s.withOutHeaders("Etag", "AnotherTagSetByAssetsAtButIDontWant")
```

[`SimpleResult`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.SimpleResult) is a `case class` and there is method `copy` in all `case class`es.

Field `header` is an instance of case class `ResponseHeader` with a field `headers` of type `Map[String, String]`.

Comment: I tried `withHeader with a little correction` approach but I get `Cannot write an instance of A to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[A]` compilation error and trying to figure it out now. Thanks.

Comment: @UmutBenzer: Please add exact code you have tried. If it's possible try version with an `implicit class`.

Comment: @UmutBenzer: I cant check my code now, so it could be better if you try to replace `withHeaders` with  `withOutHeaders` when you know that `withHeaders` works.

Comment: @seina When I add the implicit class into my code, I also get the same compile error. This time from `r.copy` line. Even without using `withOutHeaders` anywhere on my code, I doesn't compile.

Comment: @UmutBenzer: try to add `implicit val writeable: Writeable[A] = r.writeable` or `import r.writeable`. See update.

Comment: @UmutBenzer: There is a difference between [`2.0.x`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L192), [`2.1.x`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L331) and [`master`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L271) branches in the definition of `SimpleResult`. It's a little confusing.

Comment: @seina Thanks for your effort. It now perfectly works. You have an extra comma at the end of s.copy line.