# How do I route an A-record to a specific controller action in Playframework 2.2.x?

Tags: routes, playframework-2.2

Basically, I wish to route all requests to a specific A-record (root domain record, e.g. http://example.com) to a specific controller action (controllers.Application.other()) in my Playframework 2.2.1 application.

Following the explanation [over here](https://jazzy.id.au/default/2013/05/08/advanced_routing_in_play_framework.html), I understand I need to override onRouteRequest in my Global object and do the injected route over there.

But for the life of me, I can't get James Roper's example to work (I assume it's because of the Playframework version). The overriden function looks as follows:

```
import ....

object Global extends WithFilters(requireSSL, new GzipFilter()) with GlobalSettings {

  override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
    (request.method, request.path) match {
      case ("GET", "example.com") => Some(controllers.Application.other)
      case _ => super.onRouteRequest(request)
    }
  }
}

    ....
```

which yields:

```
type mismatch; found : play.mvc.Result required: play.api.mvc.Handler
```

My controllers.Application.other action is extremely basic, only rendering a page:

```
public static Result other() {
  return ok(views.html.indexOther());
}
```

I also tried changing *controllers.Application.other* to *controllers.routes.Application.other*, but then it says it needs a play.api.mvc.Handler instead of a ...Call, which is to be expected I guess.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533289/overriding-onrouterequest-with-custom-handler-in-play-scala) on changing aspects of the request headers in Playframework 2.2.1 and I think it could help me solve my problem, but I can't wrap my head around representing the controller action I want to redirect the request to as a *play.api.mvc.Handler* :(.

Any help or explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `controllers.Application.other` look like?

Comment: It simply renders a page and returns the result, nothing more. I'll include it in the question.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are mixing scala and java in your app? This doesn't answer your question but using Application.scala with def index = {...} gets rid of the error for me.

Comment: We're using a number of global filters for which we need Scala :(. But as I understand it, Play is pretty much designed with mixing together Java and Scala in mind, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: we haven't been able to find a solution. We eventually decided to use a Scala controller to point the custom routes in the Global onRouteRequest override to. Works like a charm. Although mixing Scala and Java controllers feels a bit itchy.