# How to Modify response Result Body in Interceptor Play framework 2.3.8?

Tags: interceptor, playframework-2.3

```
 @Override
public Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws java.lang.Throwable {
     Promise<Result> result = this.delegate.call(ctx);
     Http.Response response = ctx.response();
     response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     return result.map(r -> {
        play.api.mvc.Result res =  r.toScala();
        final int status = r.toScala().header().status();
        if(status == 200 || status == 201) {
            String responseBody = new String(JavaResultExtractor.getBody(r, 0L));
            final Map<String,String> headers =  JavaResultExtractor.getHeaders(r);
            ResponseHeader responseHeader = res.header();
            return new Result(responseHeader, res.body());
        }
        return r;
     });
}
```

I would like to modify the body of response on interceptor ?. I can able to get the result body. So that I will modify the response. How to override the existing body response and result as Result.

Comment: you can access the response object by using the Action composition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753876/play-2-3-java-set-header-on-all-responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the body content update like this.

```
return result.map(r -> {
                final int status = r.toScala().header().status();
                if(status == 200 || status == 201) {
                    // Can change the body content here
                    Status s = status(status,new String(JavaResultExtractor.getBody(r, 0L)));
                    return s.as(JavaResultExtractor.getHeaders(r).get("Content-Type"));
                }
                return r;
             });
```