# Set custom response headers in Play 2.1 (scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, http-headers, playframework-2.0

I'm aware of [Setting HTTP headers in Play 2.0 (scala)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199490/setting-http-headers-in-play-2-0-scala)

But how do I set a custom response header like `X-Hello-World` in the play framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just:

```
Ok
  .withHeaders("X-Hello-World" -> "it's me")
```